# Seeting up a PostgreSQL database on another hard drive than my system one on OS X?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I am on OS X 10.8.3, I've install PostgreSQL from macports, but I've realized that I have not enough space on my system drive for the DB I am about to populate with data.

Is there a way to create new database on another drive/partition (not the system one, where postgres is installed)?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the new database, then create a tablespace on your external drive:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE mytablespace LOCATION '/Volumes/externaldisk/pg';
```

Then alter the database so that the new tablespace is the default location for it:

```
ALTER DATABASE MYDB TABLESPACE mytablespace;
```

The other way to do this is to just move your entire Postgres data directory to the external drive, then symbolic link the external drive directory back to the original location.

If you want to create multiple tablespaces over many drives you can also specify which tablespace a table or index should reside in using the TABLESPACE parameter in the creation DDL.

Comment: You don't really need the symbolic link. Just tell `pg_ctl` where the data directory is located using the `-D` switch. Don't know how Postgres is started on OSX, so I can't tell where this is configured.

Comment: Yeah, same. Thought a symbolic link was nice and transparent & needed no config changes.

Comment: Tablespaces on removable volumes are a pretty bad, eat-my-data idea. Really not recommended. The PostgreSQL documentation does not make it as clear as it should that tablespaces are integral parts of the DB; if you lose a tablespace you can't just drop it and keep using the rest of the DB. Removing just one tablespace and keeping the rest of the DB running could have all sorts of exciting data-munching consequences.

Comment: I am using a database for performance bashing etc, so wasn't bothered whether the database survived or not. Writing here that the database in question has been pushed to an external drive, I've unplugged the drive while postgres was connected to the database, I've restarted without the drive connected, I've copied the directory across to a different location on a different drive then updated the symlink ([instructions](http://www.databasesoup.com/2013/11/moving-tablespaces.html)) while running and connected to the database, and the database has survived it all.

Comment: Think the answer misses the SET word, ie, `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET TABLESPACE spc;`

Answer (score 8):

I very strongly recommend that you do *not* put a tablespace on an external removable drive. If the tablespaces disappears (ie: drive unplugged) you risk *severe database corruption* that will be difficult to recover from. You'll likely find permissions management a challenge, too.

You should generally `initdb` a new database cluster on the drive, then start it with `pg_ctl`. If you like you can change your launchd properties to auto-start the database (this will require messing with file permissions) or you can just manually start it with `pg_ctl` when you want to use it.

It may be easier to move the existing data directory to the new location and either create a symlink from the old location to the new one or edit your launchd configuration to tell the PostgreSQL launcher to look in the new location. If your `postgresql.conf` is outside the data directory you can just change the `data_directory` parameter in `postgresql.conf` instead.

See the PostgreSQL user manual for details on `initdb` and `pg_ctl` if you need to use them.

For how to set PostgreSQL up to start your new database on boot-up you'll want to do some learning about file permisisons and launchd properties. I don't use OS X much so I can't be of much help with this part; if you're stumped and you've done some reading to try to figure it out, consider asking for help on the OSX stack exchange site. Just remember to explain what you've tried and what you've done already. You won't need to do this if you just symlink it from the old location.

Comment: Is the table space not part of the data directory? Or is the point that if the data directory is missing, the DB won't start up and thus won't corrupt anything?